# How to use uwsgi whitelist command

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, uwsgi

how to setting whitelist in my uwsgi.ini to let it working

my ini setting:

```
[uwsgi]

http = :80
chdir = /usr/local/myproject
wsgi-file = myproject/wsgi.py
master = true
processes = 2
threads = 4
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
plugins = http,python3
stats = 127.0.0.1:5566
static-map = /static=/usr/localmyproject/static

whitelist = 127.0.0.1
```

I dont know what uwsgi doc means

https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html?highlight=whitelist#whitelist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You clearly need to add the list to iptables or ufw which will list exactly which addresses are allowed to connect. uwsgi.ini is not the right place to add white list.